# Establish which class implementation is imported to module

Tags: python, python-2.6

I wish to unittest the following:

```
import sys
if sys.platform == "darwin":
    import OSX.Leap as Leap
elif 'linux' in sys.platform:
    import Linux.Leap as Leap
```

How do I establish if I have imported OSX.Leap or Linux.Leap in my test? In other words, how do I know which version of the Leap class I have added to the module?

**UPDATE**

If I use `inspect` I can get:

```
<module 'Linux.params' from 'Linux/params.pyc'>
```

for:

```
inspect.getmodule(Leap)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the name of the module using `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> import cStringIO as c
>>> c.__name__
'cStringIO'
>>> import StringIO as c
>>> c.__name__
'StringIO'
```

For you case:

```
if 'Linux' in module_to_test.Leap.__name__:
    # Linux ...
```

---

Alternative is using `__file__` attribute. But it will not work for some module (for example C extension module)

**UPDATE** according to the OP's comment, `Leap` is not a module, but a class/type inside the module.

You can access the module name using `__module__` attribute of the class.

```
Leap.__module__
```

Or, as you did in the updated question, use [`inspect.getmodule`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) to get the module:

```
inspect.getmodule(Leap).__name__
inspect.getmodule(Leap).__file__
```

Comment: It gives the name as simply Leap. :)

Comment: @Baz, Alternatively you can also use `__file__`. I updated the ansewr accordingly. Please check it out.

Comment: This gives: AttributeError: type object 'Leap' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: @Baz, So `Leap` is not a module, but a type/class. Check out update again.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the module that was imported is available in `Leap.__name__`. An example from the standard library:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.__name__
```

'posixpath'

The `os.path` module is similar, in that it is a wrapper that imports a platform-specific module to implement a common API.

However, there will be problem if both `Linux.Leap` and `OSX.Leap` have the same value for their `__name__` attribute. In that case, you'll just have to fall back to checking the value of `sys.platform` again to know which module was imported.

Comment: It gives the name as Leap

Comment: It might be worth filing a bug report, suggesting that different modules be given different names.